# SQL filter if ID doesn't have a value in another column

Tags: sql, vertica

I have this sample table

| Payment ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Fee |
| 123 | Service |
| 123 | Finance |
| 456 | Fee |
| 456 | Service |

I'm trying to achieve a table that would filter out any row where an ID doesn't have "type" "Finance".

Expected result would be

| Payment ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | Fee |
| 456 | Service |

Comment: Doesn't sound that difficult? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Vertica sounds like a rdbms in its own right? Please don't tag multiple (SQL Server is a distinct rdbms).

Comment: NOT EXISTS would be my first thought.

Comment: Haven't had any luck with NOT EXSISTS, what would be the syntax to use?

Comment: Please show us what you tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A readable alternative is:

```
with
filter_table as (
select payment_id
from your_table
where type = 'Finance'
)    
select *
from your_table
where payment_id is not in (select id from filter_table)
```

An alternative without the sub-query could be:

```
select *
from your_table
where payment_id is not in (select id from your_table where type='Finance')
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS should work fine for you.

```
select * from TEST t
where not exists (
  select 1 from TEST
  where PAYMENTID = t.PAYMENTID and type = 'Finance')
```

[image]